# Printing array shows wrong output

Tags: java, arrays

What is wrong with this code I'm getting wrong output. I don't know what's wrong, I hope you could help me:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] data={11,22,33,55,22,88,99,77};

    SortingAlgo algo=new SortingAlgo();
    data=algo.selectionSort(data);
    System.out.println("numbers are"+ data);
  }
}
```

Other class

```
public class SortingAlgo{
  public int[] selectionSort(int[] data){
    int lenD = data.length;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lenD;i++){
      j = i;
      for(int k = i;k<lenD;k++){
        if(data[j]>data[k]){
          j = k;
        }
      }
      tmp = data[i];
      data[i] = data[j];
      data[j] = tmp;
    }
      return data;
  }
}
```

This is my out put:

```
numbers are[I@2e4b1dd8
```

Comment: That output is correct. Your expectations are wrong. Look into `Object#toString()`.

Answer (score 7):

The output is completely fine. The arrays don't override `toString()` method, so it invokes the [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, which generates that kind of representation. The output is of the form:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

For arrays, the [`Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) method uses some encoding for different element type to generate unique class name. The encoding rule is specified in the documentation.

To get the human readable representation, you can use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) method:

```
System.out.println("numbers are"+ Arrays.toString(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

The toString() for arrays is broken.  You need

```
import java.util.Arrays;

System.out.println("numbers are" + Arrays.toString(data));
```

The same applies for Arrays.equals(), Arrays.hashCode().  The Array, Arrays, ArrayUtils classes add functionality you might like arrays to have.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

However, you may find that you really want ArrayList instead.

Comment: I wouldn't call it broken. It's just not implemented. Intentionally I guess.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel maybe there is a good reason I would rather get `[I@2e4b1dd8` than the values, but I doubt it.  IMHO Its broken as there is no class for `int[]` to sub-class this behaviour.

Comment: One I could think of would be performance/output size. Not everytime `toString()` is called it is clear on what object type it is called. Having a huge array could kill performance in such a case or make a log file unreadable.

Comment: File: C:\Java\drjava\Main.java  [line: 9]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Main

Comment: @user2838362 You need to import the class before you can use it.  Your IDE should do this for you. See my update.  If you are not using an IDE, you should as it will do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: i did import the class .. import java.util.Arrays.*; and error still

Comment: @user2838362 remove the `.*`

Comment: its fixed now thanks :D i misstyped the import. thank you very much

Comment: @user2838362 Again, if you use an IDE, it will find the right package and update the imports for you.  You don't even have to think about it.

Answer (score 4):

`data` is an *array* of `int`s. You should use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29), which is implemented [this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
3860     public static String toString(int[] a) { {
3861        if (a == null)
3862            return "null";
3863        int iMax = a.length - 1;
3864        if (iMax == -1)
3865            return "[]";
3866
3867        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
3868        b.append('[');
3869        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
3870            b.append(a[i]);
3871            if (i == iMax)
3872                return b.append(']').toString();
3873            b.append(", ");
3874        }
3875    }
```

Make sure that you understand it, it will help you to understand arrays.

You can loop on the array and manually print it:

```
for(int i: data) {
    System.out.println(i + " ");
}
```

This way you have control on which values to print, e.g. even values:

```
for(int i: data) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
}
```

---

Regarding the output you are getting, this is the explanation about it:

In Java, each *object* has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` and then the hashcode.